# Can't Get Makefile to work

Tags: c++, c, linker, makefile

I'm having trouble building a makefile. My main file is a .cpp fie. In that file, there is an include that references a header file helper_funcs.h. This header file then declares various functions, each of which is defined in their own .c file. I need to compile the .c files into .o files, compile the .o files into the helper_funcs library, and then of course be able to reference them from the .cpp file (I hope that this makes sense).

This what I get when I type 'make':

`g++ -Wall -O3 -o chessboard chessboard.cpp helper_funcs.a -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT
ld: warning: ignoring file helper_funcs.a, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x2E 0x2F 0x2E 0x5F 0x43 0x53 0x43 0x49 0x78 0x32 0x32 0x39 0x2E 0x68 0x00 0x00 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): helper_funcs.a`

EDIT:
After deleting a previous build of helper_funcs.a and recompiling, the error above went away, but this is what results:

`g++ -Wall -O3 -o chessboard chessboard.cpp helper_funcs.a -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "f1(char const*)", referenced from:
      _main in chessboard-MB9B95.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [chessboard] Error 1`

```
LDFLAGS = -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT
CFLAGS = -c -g -Wall

all: chessboard

#  Generic compile rules
.c.o:
    gcc -c -O -Wall $<
.cpp.o:
    g++ -c -Wall $<

# Generic compile and link
%: %.c helper_funcs.a
    gcc -Wall -O3 -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

%: %.cpp helper_funcs.a
    g++ -Wall -O3 -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

#  Create archive
helper_funcs.a: f1.o f2.o
    ar -rcs helper_funcs.a $^
```

Here is the start of the chessboard.cpp:

```
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
#include "chessboard.h"
#include "helper_funcs.h"

using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
      // ...
      f1("arg");
      return 0;
}
```

helper_funcs.h:

```
#ifndef helper_funcs
#define helper_funcs

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#ifdef USEGLEW
#include <GL/glew.h>
#endif
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

void f1(const char* where);
void f2(const char* format , ...);

#endif
```

Here are two of the functions (these obviously have more descriptive names, but I was trying to be general at first, so I'll stick with that to avoid confusion):

f1.c

```
#include "helper_funcs.h"

void f1(const char* where)
{
   // blah blah blah
}
```

f2.c

```
#include "helper_funcs.h"

void f2(const char* format , ...)
{
   // blah blah blah
}
```

Comment: You seem to have a version of `helper_funcs.a` that was built on (or at least *for*) a different architecture. Delete `helper_funcs.a` and try `make` again.

Comment: Thank you. That was definitely part of the problem. Now I'm back to where I was earlier where I'm still not compiling correctly. My helper functions don't seem to be visible to the main program. I've updated my OP to show this 'new' error message. Thanks again!

Comment: Drive by comment: add a `clean` target for deleting all things that can be built.

Comment: Yes, I will once I get the main part of this working. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to reproduce the problem, so we'll have to take this in stages. Try this, and tell us exactly where and how it fails: `g++ -c -Wall chessboard.cpp; g++ -c -Wall f1.cpp; g++ -c -Wall f2.cpp; g++ -Wall chessboard.o f1.o f2.o -o chessboard`

Comment: It's the last one that fails `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "f1(char const*)", referenced from:
      reshape(int, int) in chessboard.o
  "f2(char const*)", referenced from:
      _main in chessboard.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
`

Comment: If I take out the function calls in the chessboard.cpp, everything compiles 'correctly', for whatever that is worth. But the whole point is that I need to be able to call these functions from within the main .cpp file.

Comment: Good! Now please show us the functions `f1` and `f2`. You can omit the stuff inside the curly braces, it's the signatures we have to look at (i.e. the first lines, the `void f1(blah blah blah)`). There may be different `f1` functions in `f1.cpp` with different signatures, but I suspect there's no `f1(char const *)`.

Comment: Thanks again. I've edited the post to the two functions. They're pretty straightforward as far as functions go, which is why I can't understand why they don't compile into the application. Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: That explains f2: there is a function `f2` that takes two arguments (or maybe more), but there is no `f2(const char*)`. That just leaves f1. Are you *sure* you're reporting it accurately? And is the source file `f1.cpp` or `f1.c`?

Comment: I'm not following. You say 'there is no f2(const char*)'. But both the .h and the .c files have the same declaration for f2. I still don't understand why the application fails to compile? Sorry to be dense, but could you explain it a little further? Thanks again! (and yes, all of the helper function files are C files (not C++)).

Comment: Take all the OpenGL stuff out, post your real code without changing the function names, remove everything from the Makefile that's not relevant, and try again, posting your results and your *exact* code being used and the *exact* error messages.

Comment: Jawohl, Herr Kommandant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code compiled as C++, the functions `f1` and `f2` must be declared `extern "C"`. You can make a conditional in the header file to provide that marking.

E.g.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void f1(const char* where);
void f2(const char* format , ...);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

The reason for this is that C++ code is compiled in a way that functions undergo a process called 'name mangling' to encode their complete type in the symbol that linkers see, to enable overload resolution across compilation units. C compilers do not do this, since C has no notion of overloading. Thus, when calling a C function from C++ code, or vice versa, the function must be declared to have C-style linkage.